# ros_arduino_bridge reconnection error

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when I

- launch the "**ros_arduino_python/arduino.launch**"

I can perfectly control the base using "**teleop_twist_keyboard**" which is publishing the *cmd_vel* topic.

But **When I shutdown the `arduino.launch` by  pressing `ctrl+c` **and try to launch the `ros_arduino_python/arduino.launch` again, **I see the connection Exception**. as below:

===============

```
Connecting to Arduino on port /dev/ARDUINOBASE ...
Serial Exception:
(<class 'serial.serialutil.SerialException'>, SerialException(), <traceback object at 0xb5f57a80>)
Traceback follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/src/ros_arduino_python/arduino_driver.py", line 73, in connect
raise SerialException
SerialException
Cannot connect to Arduino!
```

=================

The error log is below:

```
root@pirobot:~# roslaunch ros_arduino_python arduino.launch
... logging to /root/.ros/log/8e8d6d00-9f12-11e6-b069-28f3667b4dc0/roslaunch-pirobot-2919.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://pirobot:37235/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /arduino/Kd: 12
 * /arduino/Ki: 0
 * /arduino/Ko: 50
 * /arduino/Kp: 10
 * /arduino/accel_limit: 1.0
 * /arduino/base_controller_rate: 10
 * /arduino/base_frame: base_link
 * /arduino/baud: 57600
  * /arduino/encoder_resolution: 2200
  * /arduino/gear_reduction: 1.0
  * /arduino/motors_reversed: False
  * /arduino/port: /dev/ARDUINOBASE
  * /arduino/rate: 50
  * /arduino/sensors/arduino_led/direction: output
  * /arduino/sensors/arduino_led/pin: 13
  * /arduino/sensors/arduino_led/rate: 5
  * /arduino/sensors/arduino_led/type: Digital
  * /arduino/sensorstate_rate: 10
  * /arduino/timeout: 0.1
  * /arduino/use_base_controller: True
  * /arduino/wheel_diameter: 0.08
  * /arduino/wheel_track: 0.36
  * /rosdistro: indigo
  * /rosversion: 1.11.20

 NODES
 /
 arduino (ros_arduino_python/arduino_node.py)

 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://pirobot:11311

 core service [/rosout] found
 process[arduino-1]: started with pid [2937]
 Connecting to Arduino on port /dev/ARDUINOBASE ...
 Serial Exception:
 (<class 'serial.serialutil.SerialException'>, SerialException(), <traceback object at 0xb5f57a80>)
 Traceback follows:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/root/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/src/ros_arduino_python/arduino_driver.py", line 73, in connect
 raise SerialException
 SerialException
 Cannot connect to Arduino!
 [arduino-1] process has died [pid 2937, exit code 1, cmd /root/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/nodes/arduino_node.py __name:=arduino __log:=/root/.ros/log/8e8d6d00-9f12-11e6-b069-28f3667b4dc0/arduino-1.log].
 log file: /root/.ros/log/8e8d6d00-9f12-11e6-b069-28f3667b4dc0/arduino-1*.log
 all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
 shutting down processing monitor...
 ... shutting down processing monitor complete
 done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246820/ros_arduino_bridge-reconnection-error/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-10-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-10-30**:
I'm using ros_indigo

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-10-30**:
I guess that's because I used Ctrl+C to terminate the `arduino.launch`, should I always use Ctrl+Z? is there any possible solution about editing the python code? thank you!!

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-10-31**:
Ctrl-C is correct.  Ctrl-Z would put the launch process in the background.  Can you please make sure you are (a) using the indigo-dev branch of the ros_arduino_bridge package and (b) do a 'git pull' to make sure you have the latest updates?

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-10-31**:
is there any methods that I can check the version of my code? thx!!
below is my commands:
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge.git
$ cd ros_arduino_bridge
$ git checkout indigo-devel
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ catkin_make
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-11-01**:
That all looks correct.  Can you try checking out the master branch to see if that improves the serial connection?

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-02**:
I can terminate it by Ctrl+C and start it again smoothly when using master branch:

- cd ~catkin_ws/src
- git clone https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge
- cd ros_arduino_bridge
- git checkout remotes/origin/master
- cd ~catkin_ws
- catkin_make
- source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-02**:
The last test used another Arduino board(made in italy). It works well even in indigo-level. The Arduino board with which the error occurs is made in China and it will be shown as /dev/ttyUSB0 rather than this /dev/ttyACM0. I guess that's the reason: ttyUSB* vs ttyACM*

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-02**:
Hi @Pi Robot,

there is another problem i need your advise: thank you! http://answers.ros.org/question/246920/error-when-gmaping/

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-02**:
I think there is still some bug in the file `arduino_driver.py`. there is another file `create_driver.py` in the ros pkg `create_driver` and it handles well with the `/dev/ttyUSB*` and `Ctrl+C`

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-03**:
I made a lot of tests including changing the Arduino boards and up-level computers.
I think the error may be caused by my raspbian/lubuntu14.04 system which runs on an embedded computer called OrangePi, a RaspberryPi-similar embedded computer board.
I used Ubuntu Virtual Machine to test, all is OK

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-07**:
@Pi Robot, Could you get an embedded board and have a test? thank you!

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-11-08**:
@sonictl Thanks for your additional test results.  It would probably be better to continue this discussion on https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge/issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros_arduino_bridge` `indigo-devel` branch , has bug, which result in this reconnection probelm.

I solved this problem by switching to `master` branch. and `catkin_make` again.

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0